# XML - Create element - New line

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

How can i create a new line in an element?

I do:

```
$currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('code', '    test1;
test2;
test3;'));
```

However it adds `&#13;` to the end of every line. How can i get rid of that?

Comment: Hmm looks like that this is a hard thing to do :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&#13;` is the Carriage Return part of a `\r\n` style line ending. I think DOMDocument encodes it to preserve it. If you check the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends) it says that it will get normalized to `\n` if not encoded.

So you have different options:

1. Ignore the escaped entities, they get decoded in the xml parser
2. Use CDATA-Elements, the normalization is not done here, so DOMDocument sees no need to  escape the "\r".
3. Make sure that you saved your file with `\n` style line endings
4. Normalize the line endings to `\n` before creating the DOM

Here is some sample source to show the different behaviour:

```
$text = "test1;\r\ntest2;\r\ntest3;\r\n";

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$root = $dom->appendChild($root = $dom->createElement('root'));

$root->appendChild(
  $node = $dom->createElement('code')
);
// text node - CR will get escaped
$node->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($text));

$root->appendChild(
  $node = $dom->createElement('code')
);
// cdata - CR will not get escaped
$node->appendChild($dom->createCdataSection($text));

$root->appendChild(
  $node = $dom->createElement('code')
);
// text node, CRLF and CR normalized to LF
$node->appendChild(
  $dom->createTextNode(
    str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $text)
  )
);

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <code>test1;&#13;
test2;&#13;
test3;&#13;
</code>
  <code><![CDATA[test1;
test2;
test3;
]]></code>
  <code>test1;
test2;
test3;
</code>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and all this examples :)