# PHP DOMDocument::createTextNode (XML) escapes \r\n to &#13;\r

Tags: php, xml, internet-explorer

We have a problem with IE10 displaying extra lines within the <textarea>-tag. When analyzing the problem we found its related to the escaping in PHP DOMDocument (XML).

This is the process:

1. in our database we store line breaks with \r\n (HTML standard)
2. we then build our xml-layer with DOMDocument->createTextNode("first line\r\n second line");
3. in XML-output (via DOMDocument->saveXML()) we find "first line&#13;\r second line" (= escaped \r + raw \r)
4. after xslt this ends up in the <textarea> of a form and IE 10 puts an extra empty line between the lines.

as code example:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$root = $dom->createElement('root');
$dom->appendChild($root);
$text = $dom->createTextNode("first\r\nsecond"); 
$root->appendChild($text); 
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

this will print

```
...
first&#13;[\r]
second
...
```

Thats two carriage returns! Shouldn't "createTextNode" normalize any line feed/carriage return input to just \n like it is requested by the XML specification http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends ? Or at least stick with "&#13;\n" which IE 10 might be able to recognize as just one new line?

Thanks for any suggestions!

[edit:sorry post would not display "&#13;"]

Felix

Comment: What does IE have to do with this? And what stops you from simply removing the \r before creating the text node?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML - Create element - New line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525741/xml-create-element-new-line)

Comment: thanks for you answer. I did clarify the question further. As the affected site is huge and i would like to get along without str_replace for performance reasons. thanks!